# Change scale position p5 javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have a canvas with an ellipse in it. I can then compare the mouse X and mouse Y to the ellipse X and the ellipse Y for a fake, but valid, mouse 'hover' test. When I hover over the shape the canvas is scaled to twice the size as it was before, and the shape appears larger. **However, the scale always remains at the coordinates 0,0 i.e. top left.** Is there any way to change the coordinates at which the canvas is scaled at? This way, I would be able to alter the program so that, when hovering over the shape, the new canvas would scale so that the top left is my mouse position (I can move the position of the scale). I've written a little example to demonstrate where I am, currently.

```js
function setup(scaleValue) {
// create canvas and scale to value
  var canvas = createCanvas(300,200);
  scale(scaleValue);
  background(51);
  
// create ellipse
  fill(255,255,255,100);
  stroke(255,255,255);
  ellipse(30,30,40,40);
}
function draw() {
// get mouse X and Y and create an X and Y value for the ellipse
  var x = mouseX;
  var y = mouseY;
  this.position = createVector(30,30);
  
// check for mouse hover by comparing mouse X and Y to ellipse X and Y
  if (Math.abs(mouseX - this.position.x) < 30 && Math.abs(mouseY - this.position.y) < 30) {
    setup(2);
  }
  if (Math.abs(mouseX - this.position.x) > 30 && Math.abs(mouseY - this.position.y) > 30) {
    setup(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.10/p5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `translate()` function to move the origin. If you do `translate(100, 100)` for example, the origin will now be at `100,100` and anything you draw at `0,0` will now be drawn at `100,100`.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/translate).

Also, why don't you just use the distance formula, or better yet the `dist()` function, to check whether the mouse is inside the circle?

Again, more info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/dist).

Comment: Thank you. Great answer.